# May not set both `read_only` and `write_only`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my project I want to set password as both `read_only`(because I have a separate endpoint to reset password) and `write_only`(because I don't want password send in the response).

Here is my serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A Serizlier class for User """

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'phone_number', 'user_type', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = { 'password': { 'write_only': True} }
        read_only_fields = ('password',)
```

But I get an error saying:

> AssertionError at /api/user/21/
>
> May not set both `read_only` and
>   `write_only`

How can I have a field be both `read_only` and `write_only`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the **`__init__()`** method of the serializer as,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A Serizlier class for User """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.context['some_flag']:
            self.fields['password'].read_only = True
        else:
            self.fields['password'].write_only = True

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'phone_number', 'user_type', 'password')
        # extra_kwargs = { 'password': { 'write_only': True} } # remove this
        # read_only_fields = ('password',) # remove this
```

The **`some_flag`** variable is something that you should pass to the serializer either from the password reset view or from the other view

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get how to use `some_flag` ? Can you explain with an example?

Comment: Can you add those two views?

Answer (score 2):

So extending on the answer of @JPG

The Serializer

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if 'create_method' in self.context:
        self.fields['name'].write_only = True
    else:
        self.fields['name'].read_only = True
```

And the view set

```
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

def get_serializer_context(self):

    # Call Parent
    context = super().get_serializer_context()

    # Check If This Is a POST
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        context['create_method'] = True

    # Handoff
    return context
```

This will allow name to be written on POST and read only on everything else

Answer (score 0):

well - normally if you have two endpoints using a similar serializer which needs to differ only with a certain field/functionality you would create a base class and abstract it and only change/modify the parts of it that need to change. Here is what I would do.

```
class (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A Serizlier class for User """

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'phone_number', 'user_type', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = { 'password': { 'read_only': True} }


class UserSerializerForOtherView(UserSerializer):

    class Meta(UserSerializer.Meta):
        extra_kwargs = { 'password': { 'write_only': True} }
```

Now `UserSerializerForOtherView` inherits the same behaviour as `UserSerializer` and you now also have a new serializer should you want to further expand on functionality on this serializer alone.

All you will need to do is tell the other view to use the other serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of method as well:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if request and request.method in ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH']:
            self.fields.get('password').write_only = True
        else:
            self.fields.get('password').read_only = True
```